# wget reject still downloads file

Tags: unix, wget

I only want the folder structure, but I couldn't figure out how with wget. Instead I am using this:

> wget -R pdf,css,gif,txt,png -np -r http://example.com

Which should reject all the files after -R, but it seems to me wget still downloads the file, then deletes it.

Is there a better way to just get the folder structure?

> TTP request sent, awaiting response... 
>   200 OK Length: 136796 (134K)
>   [application/x-download] Saving to:
>   “example.com/file.pdf”
>
> 100%[=====================================>] 136,796      853K/s   in 0.2s
>
> 2012-10-03 03:51:41 (853 KB/s) -
>   “example.com/file.pdf”
>   saved [136796/136796]
>
> Removing
>   example.com/file.pdf since it should be rejected.

If anyone was wondering this is for a client which they can tell me the structure but it's a hassle since their IT guy has to do it, so I wanted to just get it myself.

Comment: May be you should ask this at http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You might be better off obtaining the structure from your client. `wget`, especially with the `-np` option, may miss out dirs that are not directly or indirectly linked to by the index file.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712344/mirror-http-website-excluding-certain-files

Comment: @ShawnChin The program will only download from their website, and all the needed folders have links to them. But thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That appears to be how `wget` was designed to work. When performing recursive downloads, non-leaf files that match the reject list are still downloaded so they can be harvested for links, then deleted.

From the in-code comments ([recur.c](http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/wget/trunk/annotate/head:/src/recur.c#L426)):

> Either --delete-after was specified, or **we loaded this
>     otherwise rejected (e.g. by -R) HTML file just so we
>     could harvest its hyperlinks** -- in either case, delete
>     the local file.

We've had a run-in with this in a past project where we had to mirror an authenticated site and `wget` keeps hitting the *logout* pages even when it was meant to reject those URLs. We could not find any options to change the behaviour of `wget`.

The solution we ended up with was to [download](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/), hack and build our own version of `wget`. There's probably a more elegant approach to this, but the quick fix we used was to add the following rules to the end of the [`download_child_p()` routine](http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/wget/trunk/annotate/head:/src/recur.c#L487) (modified to match your requirements):

```
  /* Extra rules */
  if (match_tail(url, ".pdf", 0)) goto out;
  if (match_tail(url, ".css", 0)) goto out;
  if (match_tail(url, ".gif", 0)) goto out;
  if (match_tail(url, ".txt", 0)) goto out;
  if (match_tail(url, ".png", 0)) goto out;
  /* --- end extra rules --- */

  /* The URL has passed all the tests.  It can be placed in the
     download queue. */
  DEBUGP (("Decided to load it.\n"));

  return 1;

 out:
  DEBUGP (("Decided NOT to load it.\n"));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow! They should make the reject function to work like that. But I do realize that wget was meant to do a specific task. Thank you.

Comment: Upvoting this answer because it's an awesome DIY solution, but I'm still disappointed there is no better way.

Comment: working on the same issue now... logout.html.  seems to be well known as far back as 2009 and the authors apparently decided to keep this "bug" https://linuxgazette.net/160/misc/lg/how_to_make_wget_exclude_a_particular_link_when_mirroring.html

Comment: In the current version (wget-1.19.5) the function is called download_child and you must set the REASON for rejection otherwise apparently defaults to success and visits the page:  /* Extra rules */
  
  if (match_tail(url, "logout.html", 0)) 
    {
      blacklist_add (blacklist, url);
      DEBUGP (("Logout URL detected.\n", url));
      reason = WG_RR_BLACKLIST;
      goto out;
    }

  /* --- end extra rules --- */

Comment: this is some convoluted mess, why is there no option --skip-download or something